# Change Default Image From Resource

Tags: c#, image, resources, default

i have code for edit form like this

```
if (image == "" ) {
   pictureBoxImage.Image = Properties.Resources.noimage;
}
else{
   pictureBoxImage.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(Global.myPictureLocation, image);
   pictureBoxImage.BringToFront();
}
```

that works fine until i set default image from resource folder. if i set image from resource folder and not browse image that code goes error....
i try to modif it like this

```
if (image == Properties.Resources.noimage ) {
   pictureBoxImage.Image = Properties.Resources.noimage;
}
else{
   pictureBoxImage.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(Global.myPictureLocation, image);
   pictureBoxImage.BringToFront();
}
```

but it goes with error...

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

how to properly way to detect if it's image from resource or not?

Answer (score 0):

`image` is a string and you cannot compare that to an Image file.

You can try something like

```
if (Image.FromFile(image) == Properties.Resources.noimage))
```

or better yet

```
if (Image.Equals(Image.FromFile(image), Properties.Resources.noimage))
```

Comment: @user3184196 You can compare the Image file itself instead or use image tags

Comment: i get error "this path is not legal form" with first & second code,..i don't know why

Comment: i already solved it...just need to assign image = ""; then everything goes as i wish....thanks for u help, it's inspirate me